# Bring back the object browser in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, vba, microsoft-word-2013

In previous Word versions there was a very handy feature called "object browser" that allowed you to quickly navigate a document. Here is a very simple explanation of what it does: http://www.upstarts.net/article18.htm and it looked like this:

[image: Word Object Browser Location][image: Word Object Browser Menu]

That menu is gone. (It has been somewhat changed: you can use the search/navigation pane for browsing pictures and tables, but not field codes or headings or other objects. **Alt+Ctrl+Home doesn't work either.**) The browse next and previous are available for the Quick Access Toolbar via the "All Commands" listing, but the orb with the menu isn't.

**Is there any way to bring it back?** Maybe invocking the menu with a VBA keystroke?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the keyboard shortcut Alt+Ctrl+Home?

Comment: I should've stated in the post that the shortcut doesn't work - sorry! I fixed it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simpler way to browse by objects which aren't listed by default in the dropdown menu next to the search box in the Navigation pane.  Within the drop down next to the search box, select "Go To", and then within the "Find and Replace" dialogue box, select the "Go To" tab.  On this tab there's a list on the left where you can select the object type, and then Previous/Next buttons.  If you added Previous/Next buttons to your Quick Access Toolbar, you can select the browse object type in this window, close it, and then use the buttons in your toolbar to keep browsing.  Certainly not as simple/elegant as the previous version with buttons at the bottom of the vertical scroll bar, but it gets the job done.

The screenshot below shows these steps. Note that simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> does all the hassles, so you don't need to open the "Go To" dialog box via Navigation panel.

[image: Opening "Go To" dialog box via Navigation panel]

Comment: I've downgraded to Office 2010, so I can't test to see how your proposal works out. It does sound as if it should work. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Since I used to browse through comments only, I wrote a macro (see below) and assigned it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>.

I haven't found the original form to display for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>. If you need to select objects to browse through you can write a macro which would set the appropriate target.

```
Sub resetBrowser()
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseComment
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice solution. It got me thinking about replacing that menu with a ribbon tab for browsing, if I have enough time.

Answer (score 0):

In Office 2016 you can add "Go To next Section" and "Go To Previous Section" to Quick Tool Bar.  Other "Go To" options are also available.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is hidden in Word 2013, but does exist.  No need for fancy macros.  Just locate the "Browse Up" and the "Browse Down" tools and add them to your quicktools.

Comment: Since the tools are hidden you should provide more information on how to find them.  Users unfamilar with Word will have trouble finding them since you didn't provide any information.

Answer (score -1):

Go to View, select navigation panel, click on the combobox next to the search box, then click search images.

Comment: As I said in the post, _It [the menu that existed prior to wd2013] has been somewhat changed: you can use the search/navigation pane for browsing pictures and tables, but not field codes or headings or other objects._ Thanks, though.